# How to properly escape quote in sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a CSV, where values are separated by semicolon.
I need to get data in that CSV to existing collection in MongoDB database, which is actually unrelated in case of this problem.

To make it easier, I will just use one sample row from that CSV:

```
echo '1243;firstName' | sed "s:\([0-9]*\)\;\(.*\):mongo localhost/test --eval \\\\'db.test.update({_id\: \1}, {name\: \"\2\"})\\\\':" | xargs -I {} sh -c "{}"

MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: localhost/test
Thu Apr  4 22:50:10 ReferenceError: firstName is not defined (shell eval):1
```

The problem is, that when the query gets to MongoDB interpreter, it's unescaped.

I already tried to add up to 3 another backlashes in front of each quote, but nothing has changed. How should I escape quotes properly so that they will stay there until the query gets to MongoDB interpreter?

Comment: Post the desired output of your sed command rather than just describing it. Test that if sed produces that output, MongoDB (whatever that is!) will accept that text as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to call `mongo` directly than to try to get everything quoted just right to pass to `xargs`:

```
while IFS=';' read id firstName; do
    mongo localhost/test \
      --eval "db.test.update({_id: $id}, {name: \"$firstName\"})"
done < file.csv
```